# ZXing integration with eclipse and android, NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse, zxing

I hae the same problem as all this topics about the problems of getting zxing working on a project in android, but none of the solutions worked for me. This is the error log:

```
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:            com.google.zxing.client.android.R$layout
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at   com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:155)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
11-09 11:06:16.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried lots of combinations inside buildpath, adding the source project, adding de core.jar (named zxing-1.7.jar in my project), addiing it as external library...but when i don't get this problem at the bottom, then i get a dalvik format error, saying Lcom/zxing/android: already added.

I have also tried to put the .jar inside a folder called libs, but none working, checking and unchecking it on build path configs.

here's an image of my current Build Path order, http://postimage.org/image/f496ukwkf/ , but i tried with lots of different combinations, and none of them worked.

Thanks, i need to get it working, please.

Comment: [2012-11-09 12:32:57 - com.bcnquark.client.BCNQuark] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-11-09 12:32:57 - com.bcnquark.client.BCNQuark] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Now i get that :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to include code from `android/` in your project. You're not intended to do this, and you haven't set it up correctly either. Integrating by Intent (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) is far easier if you are new to this. No library code to mess with.